# Windows 7 right-click menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, context-menu, right-click

I've recently moved from Windows XP to Windows 7. Under Windows XP I installed various programs that added items to the menu that appears when you right-click on a file. For example, when the Vim text-editor is installed under Windows XP, it adds an "edit with Vim" item to this menu.

I've noticed that when I install these same programs under Windows 7, nothing gets added to the right-click menu,

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ShellMenuEx, which also has separate utilities for the "New" menu. There are also a boat load of other programs, all portable and require no installers.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html

Answer (score 1):

Known to work in Windows 7 (I just did this myself).

1. Go to your start menu (Click the Windows Orb).
2. Type in `regedit` in the search text field, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
3. Goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\`.
4. Under the `Shell` key create a key called `Notepad`.
5. Under `Notepad` create a key called `Command`.
6. Set the value of `(Default)` in the Command key to be `notepad %1`.

These steps can be used to add items as needed to your right click menu.

It should be noted that the key of the item under Shell will be the text you see within the menu. So you could for example replace `Notepad` with `Edit` and you'll always have the option to edit any file with Notepad, or any other text editor you wish to use just by chaging the `(Default)` of the `Command` key to another program.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is not fully compatible, at least on the install.

I think this will help you to easily add what you are missing:

http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html

http://download.cnet.com/FileMenu-Tools/3000-2094_4-10810545.html?tag=mncol;1

Answer (score 0):

For example 7zip does this, and it works just fine under Win7, identically as it did under XP. So, I'm inclined to think it's a matter of the software doing it correctly.